# Reference to Unintialized collection exception using array PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting reference to uninitialized collection exception when trying to add element to an array. Please help.Is that correct way to initialize the array as mentioned in my calling code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SCHEMA.STRARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.PR_VALIDATE 
(
FILEARRAY IN STRARRAY,
DUPARRAY OUT STRARRAY)
IS
dupCount NUMBER;
fileName VARCHAR2 (50);
fileId NUMBER;
dupfileName VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
 for i in 1 .. FILEARRAY.count
   loop
     fileName := FILEARRAY(i);


     SELECT COUNT (T.FILEID), T.FILEID INTO dupCount,fileId FROM TB_COMPANY T, TB_COMPANY S
     WHERE T.FILEID=S.FILEID
     AND T.RPDT_ORI_FLE_NM = fileName AND T.RPDT_STA_CD IN ('PASS', 'FAIL')
     GROUP BY T.FILEID;


     IF dupCount>1
     THEN 
     SELECT RPDT_ORI_FLE_NM INTO dupfileName FROM TB_RDTE_COMPANY_HDR_DT
     WHERE RPDT_STA_CD IN ('PR15','PR16') AND RPDT_FLE_ID=fileId
     AND RPDT_ORI_FLE_NM != fileName;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dupfileName);
     DUPARRAY(DUPARRAY.LAST +1 ) :=dupfileName;  --Here is the exception.
     END IF;
    end loop;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
        PR_RDTE_ERRORS('PR_VALIDATE', SQLERRM);
       ROLLBACK;

END;
/
```

**Calling code:**

```
DECLARE
DUPARRAY STRARRAY:=STRARRAY();


BEGIN
PR_VALIDATE        (STRARRAY('abc.txt'),DUPARRAY);
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DUPARRAY.LAST` will get the index of the last element of the array (and not the index of the last non-`NULL` value of the array) - so if you use `DUPARRAY.LAST + 1` you will always exceed the array bounds.

Also, you have not extended the array - which you need to do to add an extra element.

You need to do:

```
DUPARRAY.EXTEND;
DUPARRAY(DUPARRAY.LAST) :=dupfileName;
```

You also need to initialise the `DUPARRRY` inside the procedure (instead of in the calling code):

So something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_VALIDATE 
(
  FILEARRAY IN  STRARRAY,
  DUPARRAY  OUT STRARRAY
)
IS
dupCount NUMBER;
fileName VARCHAR2 (50);
dupfileName VARCHAR2(50);
fileId NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DUPARRAY := STRARRAY();

  for i in 1 .. FILEARRAY.count loop
     fileName := FILEARRAY(i);

     SELECT COUNT (T.FILEID), T.FILEID
     INTO   dupCount,fileId
     FROM   TB_COMPANY T
            INNER JOIN TB_COMPANY S
            ON T.FILEID=S.FILEID
     WHERE T.RPDT_ORI_FLE_NM = fileName
     AND   T.RPDT_STA_CD IN ('PASS', 'FAIL')
     GROUP BY T.FILEID;

     IF dupCount>1 THEN 
       SELECT RPDT_ORI_FLE_NM
       INTO   dupfileName
       FROM   TB_RDTE_COMPANY_HDR_DT
       WHERE  RPDT_STA_CD IN ('PR15','PR16')
       AND    RPDT_FLE_ID=fileId
       AND    RPDT_ORI_FLE_NM != fileName;

       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dupfileName);

      DUPARRAY.EXTEND;
      DUPARRAY(DUPARRAY.LAST) :=dupfileName;
    END IF;
  end loop;
END;
/
```

Then call it:

```
DECLARE
  DUPARRAY STRARRAY;
BEGIN
  PR_VALIDATE(STRARRAY('abc.txt'),DUPARRAY);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you..Even after adding extend and DUPARRAY.LAST, i am getting the same exception. :(  Is that something wrong in my calling code?

Comment: @Karthik You also have an extra comma on line 4 of the procedure.

Comment: Yeah..that was copying mistake..that comma is not there in my procedure now..no compilation errors..only runtime error which i mentioned..I will edit my question..Thanks for that..But unable to resolve that error somehow

Comment: @Karthik You also haven't declared the `dupFileName` variable.

Comment: My bad..Actually thats a very big procedure, i just cut some parts of it to show that error. Even dupfileName is declared in the code..

Comment: @Karthik Updated - I couldn't see the error for looking - but you are right it was with the calling code (the `DUPARRAY` needed initialising inside the procedure and not in the anonymous block it was being called from).